# Access VBA Function = "Undefined function 'DSimpleRegress' in expression

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

Got some code that works in a Access 2000 format but not in Access 2010. I have tried un-selecting MS 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Libaray and selecting the ActiveX 2.1 and DAO 3.6 libaries that are selected in the 2000 instance but still getting the same error.

Any suggestion to code changes or other solutions?

Code is as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Enumeration used for determining which regression stat(s) the DSimpleRegress function returns

Enum SimpleRegressStat
    SimpleRegressStat_All = 0
    SimpleRegressStat_RSquared = 1
    SimpleRegressStat_XCoeff = 2
    SimpleRegressStat_Intercept = 3
    SimpleRegressStat_SE_Resid = 4
    SimpleRegressStat_SE_XCoeff = 5
    SimpleRegressStat_SE_Intercept = 6
    SimpleRegressStat_T_XCoeff = 7
    SimpleRegressStat_T_Intercept = 8
End Enum

Function DSimpleRegress(X_Column As String, Y_Column As String, Tbl As String, _
    Optional Criteria As String = "", Optional Stat As Variant = "")

    ' Function by Patrick G. Matthews

    ' Feel free to use and distribute this code, so long as you credit authorship and indicate the
    ' URL where you found it

    ' This function calculates statistics for simple linear regression between a single independent
    ' variable (X_Column) and a dependent variable (Y_Column), and is intended for use in Microsoft
    ' Access.  This function requires a reference to the Microsoft DAO library.

    ' Depending on the value of the Stat argument, this function returns a single regression
    ' statistic, such as the R squared or the X coefficient, or it returns an array of all
    ' available regression stats (for a list of available stats, please see the enumeration
    ' SimpleRegressStat)

    ' If either or both corresponding values in the paired X, Y data set are null, those records
    ' are ignored

    ' This function is labeled according to the domain aggregate function naming convention as it
    ' behaves similarly to the other domain aggregates

    ' X_Column is the independent variable
    ' Y_Column is the dependent variable
    ' Tbl is the source table or query for the data
    ' Criteria defines any filtering criteria you wish to apply to the data set.  Be sure to enclose
    '       text items in single quotes and date values in the # date qualifiers
    ' Stat determines which regression statistic the function returns.  For a full list of the valid
    '       values (NOT case sensitive) for the Stat argument, see the Select Case structure under
    '       the label DetermineMode

    ' For each of the arguments, I strongly recommend that you encase column and table names in
    ' square brackets.  This is mandatory of the column/table name does not follow the usual rules
    ' for naming database objects

    Static Last_X_Column As String
    Static Last_Y_Column As String
    Static Last_Tbl As String
    Static Last_Criteria As String
    Static Last_Runtime As Date
    Static Result_RSquared As Variant
    Static Result_XCoeff As Variant
    Static Result_Intercept As Variant
    Static Result_SE_Resid As Variant
    Static Result_SE_XCoeff As Variant
    Static Result_SE_Intercept As Variant
    Static Result_T_XCoeff As Variant
    Static Result_T_Intercept As Variant

    Dim N As Long
    Dim AvgX As Variant
    Dim AvgY As Variant
    Dim AvgXY As Variant
    Dim VarPX As Variant
    Dim VarPY As Variant
    Dim Covar As Variant

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Mode As SimpleRegressStat
    Dim Results(1 To 8) As Variant

    Const ForceRefreshSeconds As Long = 30

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

DetermineMode:

    ' Determines whether a single regression stat is returned (and if so, which), or whether
    ' an array of all available stats is returned

    Select Case LCase(Stat)
        Case "1", "r squared", "rsquared", "r sq", "rsq", "r square", "rsquare", "r-squared", "r-squared", _
            "r-sq", "r-sq", "r-square", "r-square"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_RSquared
        Case "2", "x", "x coefficient", "x coeff", "xcoeff", "coeff", "coefficient"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_XCoeff
        Case "3", "intercept", "constant"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_Intercept
        Case "4", "se model", "se regression", "se resid", "se residual", "se residuals", "std error model", _
            "std error regression", "std error resid", "std error residual", "std error residuals", _
            "standard error model", "standard error regression", "standard error resid", _
            "standard error residual", "standard error residuals"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_SE_Resid
        Case "5", "se x", "se x coefficient", "se x coeff", "se xcoeff", "se coeff", "se coefficient", _
            "std error x", "std error x coefficient", "std error x coeff", "std error xcoeff", _
            "std error coeff", "std error coefficient", "standard error x", "standard error x coefficient", _
            "standard error x coeff", "standard error xcoeff", "standard error coeff", _
            "standard error coefficient"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_SE_XCoeff
        Case "6", "se intercept", "se constant", "std error intercept", "std error constant", _
            "standard error intercept", "standard error constant"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_SE_Intercept
        Case "7", "t x", "t x coefficient", "t x coeff", "t xcoeff", "t coeff", "t coefficient"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_T_XCoeff
        Case "8", "t intercept", "t constant"
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_T_Intercept
        Case Else
            Mode = SimpleRegressStat_All
    End Select

CalculateStats:

    ' Calculate the regression stats

    ' This function holds the regression stats in static variables, which retain their state
    ' between calls.  If the values for the X_Column, Y_Column, Tbl, and Criteria arguments
    ' are the same as those for the last call, and if the seconds elapsed since the last
    ' call are less than what is specified in the ForceRefreshSeconds constant, then we can
    ' skip the calculations and go right to assigning the return value

    If DateDiff("s", Last_Runtime, Now) >= ForceRefreshSeconds Or Last_X_Column <> X_Column Or _
        Last_Y_Column <> Y_Column Or Last_Tbl <> Tbl Or Last_Criteria <> Criteria Then

        ' Initialize stats to null

        Result_RSquared = Null
        Result_XCoeff = Null
        Result_Intercept = Null
        Result_SE_Resid = Null
        Result_SE_XCoeff = Null
        Result_SE_Intercept = Null
        Result_T_XCoeff = Null
        Result_T_Intercept = Null

        ' All the regression stats can be calculated from the following six values: N, Avg(X), Avg(Y),
        ' Avg(X * Y), VarP(X), and VarP(Y).  Use the following SQL statement to get these six values

        SQL = "SELECT Count(1) AS N, Avg(" & X_Column & ") AS AvgX, Avg(" & Y_Column & ") AS AvgY, " & _
            "Avg(" & X_Column & " * " & Y_Column & ") AS AvgXY, VarP(" & X_Column & ") AS VarPX, " & _
            "VarP(" & Y_Column & ") AS VarPY " & _
            "FROM " & Tbl & " " & _
            "WHERE " & IIf(Trim(Criteria) <> "", Criteria & " And ", "") & X_Column & " Is Not Null " & _
                "And " & Y_Column & " Is Not Null"

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

        ' Transfer values from recordset to variables, then close recordset

        AvgX = CDbl(rs!AvgX)
        AvgY = CDbl(rs!AvgY)
        AvgXY = CDbl(rs!AvgXY)
        N = rs!N
        VarPX = CDbl(rs!VarPX)
        VarPY = CDbl(rs!VarPY)
        Covar = AvgXY - AvgX * AvgY

        rs.Close

        ' There must be at least 3 valid data points for regression to work.  If there are 2 or
        ' fewer data points, we skip the rest of the calculations, thus allowing the regression
        ' stats to remain as null

        If N > 2 Then

            ' Calculate various stats

            Result_RSquared = Covar ^ 2 / (VarPX * VarPY)

            Result_XCoeff = Covar / VarPX

            Result_Intercept = AvgY - AvgX * Result_XCoeff

            Result_SE_Resid = ((N / (N - 2)) * (VarPY - Covar ^ 2 / VarPX)) ^ 0.5

            Result_SE_XCoeff = Result_SE_Resid * (1 / (N * VarPX)) ^ 0.5

            Result_SE_Intercept = Result_SE_Resid * ((VarPX + AvgX ^ 2) / (N * VarPX)) ^ 0.5

            Result_T_XCoeff = Result_XCoeff / Result_SE_XCoeff

            Result_T_Intercept = Result_Intercept / Result_SE_Intercept

        End If

    End If

ReturnValue:

    ' Set the fnction's return value

    Select Case Mode
        Case SimpleRegressStat_All
            Results(1) = Result_RSquared
            Results(2) = Result_XCoeff
            Results(3) = Result_Intercept
            Results(4) = Result_SE_Resid
            Results(5) = Result_SE_XCoeff
            Results(6) = Result_SE_Intercept
            Results(7) = Result_T_XCoeff
            Results(8) = Result_T_Intercept
            DSimpleRegress = Results
        Case SimpleRegressStat_RSquared
            DSimpleRegress = Result_RSquared
        Case SimpleRegressStat_XCoeff
            DSimpleRegress = Result_XCoeff
        Case SimpleRegressStat_Intercept
            DSimpleRegress = Result_Intercept
        Case SimpleRegressStat_SE_Resid
            DSimpleRegress = Result_SE_Resid
        Case SimpleRegressStat_SE_XCoeff
            DSimpleRegress = Result_SE_XCoeff
        Case SimpleRegressStat_SE_Intercept
            DSimpleRegress = Result_SE_Intercept
        Case SimpleRegressStat_T_XCoeff
            DSimpleRegress = Result_T_XCoeff
        Case SimpleRegressStat_T_Intercept
            DSimpleRegress = Result_T_Intercept
    End Select

    Last_Runtime = Now

    GoTo Cleanup

ErrHandler:
    SimpleRegress = CVErr(Err.Number)

Cleanup:
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? You've shown us the function definition, but somewhere else you must be trying to use it and are getting the "undefined function" error.

Comment: Running it in a simple query as a test for the moment to get out option 2 (XCoeff) XCoeff: DSimpleRegress("X","Y","Query1","'",2)

Comment: Are you running the query in an Access session which has the database which contains `DSimpleRegress` open?

Comment: Running the query and have the module both in the same database. The module is closed whilst I am trying to run the query

Comment: Did you save your module using a different name from your function name?